# Add two comment lines to the top of a file

Tags: sed

I am trying to have a sed script that makes changes and outputs a new file, but it must add two comment lines to the top, so that the output file can then be itself run as a bash script. The trouble is that all the solutions I have seen for adding two top lines do not apply to comments, which render the script itself non-functioning.

So for example if my sed results in a file like this:

```
AAAA
BBBB
CCCC
DDDD
```

I want to end up with something looking like this:

```
#$ -cwd
#$ -pe mpi 16

AAAA
BBBB
CCCC
DDDD
```

I have already tried variations on things like this:

```
sed -i '1s/^/#$ -cwd\n/' output.txt
```

But these will treat everything past the # as comment.

How can I write a bash script that will add the comment headers without messing itself up?
Thanks!

Comment: Try using ‘i’ instead of ‘s’ command inside sed

Comment: it should be a job for "cat" (which is short for : concatenate) :  `cat  header  originalfile > newfile`. If you inted to instead add lines "infile" (ie, without going with a secondary filename), you can indeed use sed  (or even : ed) for this.

Comment: And probably escape  \#

Comment: You say "so that the output file can then be itself run as a bash script." how with the output that you show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid all problems with having to quote special characters etc. for use with `sed`, use a quoted here-document:

```bsh
cat - output.txt <<'END_COMMENTS' >newfile.txt
#$ -cwd
#$ -pe mpi 16

END_COMMENTS
```

This concatenates your three lines of extra text with the contents of your existing file `output.txt`, and places the resulting text in `newfile.txt`. You are then free to rename `newfile.txt` into `output.txt` if you want.

The `cat` command is used with two arguments here:

1. `-`; this instructs `cat` to first read from standard input.  The standard input stream will contain the here-document containing your header text.
2. `output.txt`; this is your existing file. It will be read whenever the data arriving on standard input is all read.

Testing:

```
$ cat output.txt
AAAA
BBBB
CCCC
DDDD
```

The `>` prompt at the start of the lines below is the secondary prompt of the `bash` shell, used when more input is needed to complete a command.

```
$ cat - output.txt <<'END_COMMENTS' >newfile.txt
> #$ -cwd
> #$ -pe mpi 16
>
> END_COMMENTS
```

```
$ cat newfile.txt
#$ -cwd
#$ -pe mpi 16

AAAA
BBBB
CCCC
DDDD
```

Note that if the final output is supposed to be a `bash` shell script, then the first line of your header should be a `#!`-line with the absolute pathname of the `bash` interpreter.

---

You could also just use `printf`:

```bsh
printf '%s\n' '#$ -cwd' '#$ -pe mpi 16' '' |
cat - output.txt >newfile.txt
```

Instead of a here-document, this uses `printf` to generate the three lines of header text.  The result will be the same, but it looks uglier and you need to understand the code to see what the header text actually looks like (unless you run it, obviously).

Answer (score 2):

Kusalananda's answer is probably the best solution as it will always work, but I have also verified that using a sed only solution works too:

```
$ cat output.txt 
AAAA
BBBB
CCCC
DDDD
$ sed '1i#$ -cwd\n#$ -pe mpi 16\n' output.txt 
#$ -cwd
#$ -pe mpi 16

AAAA
BBBB
CCCC
DDDD
```

Basically using sed's (i)nsert command instead of (s)ubstitute:
`1` - operate on line 1
`i` - insert before
`1i` - insert before line 1

This works using gnu sed 4.8. YMMV